# PDF pages show up blank after Deflate compression

Tags: .net, pdf, gzip, zlib, compression

I have created an application in .NET which creates simple text based PDF files from scratch. I have been successful in creating PDF files where I put content text as it is e.g. Td (Hello World) Tj.

But now I want to reduce the size of the PDf files by applying some form of compression to the content. I have so far implemented native .NET Gzip and zlib compression classes. I have managed to compress the content (text) and reduce the size of the PDF file considerably. But the catch is that when I open PDF file in Acrobet reader, the file/pages are blank with no content. Although when I open the PDF file in Notepad, I can see the content has been compressed.

What am I doing wrong? below is something that I am doing when writing PDF content. Am I missing some required PDF element tags? Below compression is zlib.

```
5 0 obj<</Filter /FlateDecode/Length 571>>stream
xœíVM›0½#ñæØî!;6ØàÜ€°›¨Xâ´? R«Vê¥=Tê¯ïÂGøPÚlw%F€åÁï=?Ð |¶-_À¶Bm[÷påþd[ú#Ðå']@ÿ †füeRß«E 0NS4ƒ#AHºõ*é;xóV}Wpe|ˆ:"ƒôÝ.}„(+ò¬ô.KG×3~OGÆ€¹k¦Ö§Ž0×EÅÈfb¡È‹,{ˆ7P‚dwÐªÇ0,šŽ“à?UÏmâ‚(ÊŽ©®K•©}=‚Ãvi™-çÛ'x$Ç¸ÎtŸ67ƒýij&éqoø‘F4dDóRË—™éÊY”è(”Êi4ôÑ[    ìª*y/S®Z!Î—òŠè¼Xª•qŸ§$¯ªüQÈ¼Ò÷u8^   ]ß
Îó ©b„£8!xŠ{õs¡×T#rÎ¥ÃÚzWxî9dªE·¤:ü>dD• nŒ8E•~I\€Ît¬§ÞÀ™è]#œp:LûZî·ð|å2AÑ”ãxYËÓ¢ÛÚ†Ká»R4Ÿ®ïVð«;ó´eÚ§ÚgAm/Tvœ?Ø%æìR«¨±
C"ÈUç!¡|WÈ—E†™Sê¶›%¸Á%[ã³v³$ð—›5Ík˜¹n³fU~¤Ê›K…who`Ú¯s˜Ôã9ƒýhKK¹´”KK9ˆ¥¥<[´´”KKÙ«wKK9+––rKKùÿ¢ÛRÚV¬u…à
endstream
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, compressed data is invalid. Acrobat fails to decode it and treat stream as empty.

I would suggest you to check you compression code. You might want to try to compress something using your code and one of compression libraries you can find on the web. Then compare the results.